# Implementing OpenId in my custom application where users are created by administrator only

Tags: asp.net, openid

In my asp.net application, users are created by the administrators & those users need to log-in into the system using their own email/password or openid. So what is the best option to implement in this scenario?

I mean, as users can't register them self,do administrator required to associate each openid with the users & what kind of table structure do I need?

And do I also need the log-in interface like that of stackoverflow.com showing multiple types of authentication(default & openid from various providers)?

Answer (score 1):

if the below suits you can set it up this way:-

- Have user come up to your site and try logging in.
- Do the complete OpenID authentication fetching one pseudonym from OpenID which can be used as a unique user identifier
- Once verified , check if the user exists in your database of authorized user. if not , add this to a sperate table of new_users. For the new user , show a message which is akin to "You can login to the site once admin authroizes you"
- Provide an interface for admin to look into new_users
- Allow admin to authorize the new user. This would move the user to authorized user based on your business criteria
- Once authorized , user can login to the site.

P.S: Take a look at http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe

Comment: @ramkumar, would appreciate if you could let us know if the answer suits your requirements or not!